# Windows Server 2012 as web server with user authentication - VL/SPLA - is it legal?

Tags: web-server, windows-server-2012, licensing

I've been wrapping my head around the topic for a few days now and the more I read the less I understand.

Question 1: If I purchase a license for Windows 2012 Server (either Essential/Standard/DataCenter) - am I allowed to use it run publicly accessible web server, with the  assumption that some part of the website requires user authentication (authentication by means of web application itself).

Examples of a software that could run on such web server:

- shop, where registered users can purchase items
- paid forums
- on-line task management systems that users (customers) purchase subscription access to

It seems to me, that it is not legal (or at least not economical), since according to my understanding of Microsoft's licensing terms:

- I need to purchase CALs for each *non-anonymous* user accessing the s.c. web workloads
- all users authenticating by any means (not necessarily Windows accounts) are considered *non-anonymous*
- thus I would need like thousands of CALs for each potential user of i.e. forum (or purchase External Connector license, but I am not sure whether this is available for Windows Server 2012)

On the other hand, the discontinued Windows Web Edition (which license include s.c. "CAL waiver") made no restrictions on whether the web-workload users where *non-authenticated* or *authenticated* ones. So maybe my understanding is wrong, and CALs/EC are not required for *authenticated users accessing web-workloads only*?

Reference information:

- http://blogs.softchoice.com/microsoftnavigator/licensing/microsoft-server-2012-licensing-changes-6-key-things-you-need-to-know/
- http://microsoftlicensereview.com/tag/when-do-i-need-a-cal/
  http://blogs.technet.com/b/volume-licensing/archive/2014/03/10/licensing-how-to-when-do-i-need-a-client-access-license-cal.aspx
- http://www.picacommunications.com/briefs/SLA_WinServer_ExternalAccess.pdf
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/volume-licensing/archive/2014/03/10/licensing-how-to-when-do-i-need-a-client-access-license-cal.aspx

Question 2: If not - is SPLA a solution in this scenario?

If I license Windows Server through SPLA - is scenario described above legal?

Question 3: Is Essentials edition less restrictive since it does not require CALs?

Windows 2012 Server Essentials does not require CALs, but is limited to 25 users. Is this legal or technical limit? Would Essentials edition be valid in scenario described above?

Comment: I'm afraid you're not going to find many people who know licensing that well here. As mentioned [in the canonical answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue/215436#215436) licensing tends to fall on the purchasing office / managerial staff, not the sysadmins.

Comment: The funny thing is this part `"So maybe my understanding is wrong, and CALs/EC are not required for authenticated users accessing web-workloads only?"` could likely be answered by the folks that host StackExchange since it is a Windows server platform with authentication for a web workload.

Comment: I am awaiting answer then… ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is highlighted by one of the references you linked:

> 5 – Do I need a CAL when my Windows Server is used to run a web
>   server?
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 configured to run Web Workloads ** do not
>   require CALs or External Connectors.  Web workloads, also referred to
>   as an internet web solution, are publically accessible (e.g.
>   accessible outside of the firewall) and consist only of web pages, web
>   sites, web applications, web services, and/or POP3 mail serving. 
>   Access to content, information, and/or applications within the
>   internet web solution must be publically accessible.  In other words,
>   they cannot be restricted to you or your affiliate’s employees.
>
> **If you have Windows Servers configured to run a “web workload” these
>   users will not require CALs or External Connectors.**  However, let’s
>   say you are using Windows Server to setup an online store where
>   customers can buy widgets.  You have front end Windows Servers setup
>   to support your website, and backend servers (e.g. commerce servers)
>   setup so customers can check out and buy your widgets.  The front end
>   servers used to host your website would generally be considered as
>   running “web workloads” and CALs or External Connectors will not be
>   required to access these servers.  Once the customer adds a widget to
>   their shopping cart, creates an account and enters their credit card
>   and shipping information to complete the sale – they are now
>   authenticated via your back end commerce servers/application (non-web
>   workload).  Since users are accessing the backend commerce servers
>   which web workloads are not running – CALs or External Connectors will
>   be required for users to access these back end servers.

However, you *do* need an External Connector license if you're using backend servers to handle things like authentication and order processing. This license is available for 2012.

Comment: I am aware of this, but this whole paragraph is in contradiction to what other sources state (in general: that 2012 licensing/PURs no longer state that "web workload" must be unauthenticated).

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I honestly believe the wording of a technet blog article more than 3rd party sites. The best *possible* way of knowing the right way to go is to ask a MS partner.

Comment: And I really like the part, that "web workloads" include "POP3 mail serving", which obviously require accessing users to be authenticated. :-)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This is an old post - but on the front page of Google. My 2 cents: The contents of a blog, even if it's an official MS blog, does not constitute part of the legally binding agreement you have with Microsoft. Refer to the product terms and your volume licence agreement for details. If further clarity is required then ask your MS account manager/rep, and then go further and insist they backup their answer with references from the product terms and volume licence agreement. Nowhere does it state that a commerce checkout back-end server doesn't constitute a "web workload"